# What is the use of Javascript cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Most cookies tend to be (or *should be*, as suggested by many) `HttpOnly`, which means that they cannot be modified or retrieved using Javascript.

Yet, there are Javascript methods available for manipulating cookies on the client-side. If Javascript cookies are indeed bad for the security, what is the use of having them?

In other words, is there any **both legitimate and safe** use case for Javascript cookies?

Comment: in my opinion, the use of cookies is obsoleted by web storage, except in cases where you're storing user preferences. that being said, this question is asking for opinions and should be closed as such.

Comment: Why are you using cookies for security purposes? They are not safe and they can be changed/faked easily on any http request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some cookies may be valuable for preserving UI status (window size, theme, etc). There's not much of a security issue with those.

Comment: so if the data inside is not identity or login sensitive, but is only there to support some application logic, then it's safe to use non-`HttpOnly` cookie?

Comment: Well yes; it's safe when it's safe :-)  Some information pertaining to how a particular user uses an application isn't really sensitive, but exactly what is and isn't sensitive is a judgment call you have to make.